# Restore menu items states using Navigation with BottomNavigationView + FloatingActionButton (FAB)

Tags: android, navigation, floating-action-button, bottomnavigationview

How can I `setupWithNavController` my BottomNavigationView with a FloatingActionButton (FAB) on top?

[Thanks StackOverflow for hating me and not letting me display photos. :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPmPS.png)

According to the Navigation library releases…

> Starting in [Navigation 2.4.0-alpha01](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.4.0-alpha01), the state of each menu item is
> saved and restored when you use `setupWithNavController`.

This works like a charm, however, when I setup my BottomNavigationView and press the FAB, the states of the current menu items are reloaded. How can I achieve the same behavior of clicking on any menu item with the FAB?

```
binding.activityMainBottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)

binding.activityMainFloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener {

    // TODO: Fix navigation.
    navController.navigate(R.id.homeFragment)

    binding.activityMainBottomNavigationView.selectedItemId = R.id.homeFragment      
}
```

As I understand, calling `navController.navigate()` may be resetting the current `nav_graph` used by the `fragmentContainerView` and that's why the current menu items are being reloaded. Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a week of several attempts, I achieved the desired purpose using `onNavDestinationSelected` from `NavigationUI`.

```
binding.activityMainBottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)

binding.activityMainFloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener {

    NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(
        binding.activityMainBottomNavigationView.menu.findItem(R.id.homeFragment),
        navController
    )

    binding.activityMainBottomNavigationView.selectedItemId = R.id.homeFragment
}
```

In this way, the states of the fragments and navigation survive!

Cheers!